# How do we get the count of a list in my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The query I wrote works perfectly the only problem is that I need to get the count of the rows instead of the full list.

For example: here is my output and my query:

Comment: That query is kinda hard to read.  Or even to see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query like following.

```
select count(*) totalcount from
(
    select count(employeeid) ct
    from eventmanagment 
    group by employeeid
    having count(*) > 5
)t
```

Comment: what err are you getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')t
select count(employeeid) totalcount from
(
select count(employeeid) A
 from eventmanagment at line 1
mysql>

Comment: wait i got another error i managed to fix the one i send in few sec

Comment: the error now is this:  Unknown column 'employeeid' in 'field list'

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need the count(employeeid).  Just use employeeid.  So you can change your query to just select count(*) from (select employeeid from ... group by employeeid having ...) t.   Where the ellipses indicate the current values you have.